# HTML button onserverclick is not working in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, servercontrols

I had a problem in the event onserverclick. I have created an HTML server-side button "btnsubmit" in tab_1:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Skripsi.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
        <img src="/Image/fti-untar.png" alt="untar" />
        <h2>Layanan</h2>
        <br />
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="pill">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="pill">Biodata</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="pill">Konsultasi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab_4" data-toggle="pill">Hasil Studi</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content col-md-10">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1" runat="server">
                <div id="panel1" class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Biodata</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <label for="id">ID</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtid" class="form-control" runat="server"/>
                        <br />
                        <label for="nama">Nama</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtnama" class="form-control" />
                        <br />
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtemail" class="form-control" />
                        <br />
                        <label for="alamat">Alamat</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtalamat" class="form-control" />
                        <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" onserverclick="btnsubmit_ServerClick">Submit</input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" id="txtname" name="Name" value="" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <h4>Pane B</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada famesac turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
                <h4>Pane C</h4>
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada famesac turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_4">
                <h4>Pane D</h4>
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada famesac turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- tab content -->
    </div><!-- end of container -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Skripsi
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnsubmit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Success Horray");
        }

    }
}
```

When Pressing the button I get the following Error:

> asp runtime error(the base class includes the field 'btnsubmit', but it's type is not compatible with the type of control)

Update:
After cleaning the solution and rebuilding it I had the following error:

> 'content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for element input'.

Comment: change onserverclick to OnClick

Comment: still not working. And OnClick just working for asp:Button

Comment: Why aren't you using `asp:Button`?

Comment: If i am use asp:button, then i need to use form tag. I just do not want use form tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it's asp runtime error(the base class includes the field 'btnsubmit', but it's type is not compatible with the type of control)

From Solution Explorer window, right click on your solution and choose Clean solution and then rebuild solution

and format the element to be like this

```
<input type="button" id="btnsubmit" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" onserverclick="btnsubmit_ServerClick" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Sorry, what do u mean?

Comment: From the solution explorer menu, any way I've edited my answer for full details

Comment: I am still get error 'content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for element input'.

Comment: <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" onserverclick="btnsubmit_ServerClick" value="Submit" />

Comment: you can't add text inside <input /> tag

Comment: i solve it. it's still have to use <form id="form1" runat="server">. But i dont want it. TT

Comment: You can't opt-out of using it, the basic tag for an aspx page is the form tag

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 
"input type='button' "
instead "button" ?

```
<button id="btnsubmit" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" onserverclick="btnsubmit_ServerClick">Submit</button>
```

Comment: not working. it's asp runtime error(the base class includes the field 'btnsubmit', but it's type is not compatible with the type of control).