# Html button not firing code in behind event

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get a simple form to post to my sql database, but nothing is happening when i click on it. I have tried runat="Server, onclick, onserverclick tags but nothing is happening.

I am new to html forms so dont know if i should have the button outside of the actual form to do this? any help is greatly appreciated

Below is the html code

```
            <div class="register-content" ">
                <form  method="POST" class="margin-bottom-0">
                    <label class="control-label">Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="row row-space-10">
                        <div class="col-md-6 m-b-15">
                            <input id="First_Text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 m-b-15" >
                            <input id="Last_Text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="control-label">Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="row m-b-15">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="Email_Text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="control-label">Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="row m-b-15">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="Pass_Text" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="register-buttons">
                        <button runat="server" onserverclick="ValidateUser" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="m-t-20 m-b-40 p-b-40">
                        Already a registered user? Click <a href="login.aspx">here</a> to login.
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <p class="text-center">
                        &copy; NZAB All Right Reserved 2019
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
```

And here is the code behind

```
Protected Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim connect As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NZABFMAD_Users").ToString())
    Using coa As New SqlCommand()
        With coa
            .Connection = connect
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        End With
        Try
            connect.Open()
            Dim insertcmd As String
            insertcmd = "INSERT INTO [New_User] (Username,[First name],[Last name],Email,Password) values (@User_Text,@First_Text,@Last_Text,@Email_Text,@Pass_Text)"

            coa.CommandText = insertcmd
            coa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Text", Request.Form("User_Text"))
            coa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Text", Request.Form("First_Text"))
            coa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Text", Request.Form("Last_Text"))
            coa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_Text", Request.Form("Email_Text"))
            coa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_Text", Request.Form("Pass_Text"))
            coa.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connect.Close()
            MsgBox("success insert")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Fail to Save to database")
        End Try
    End Using

End Sub
```

Granted i will be salting/hashing passwords when storing in sql, but for now i just want the button to actually fire the event!

Comment: Have you tried removing all code and just having a function like `Protected Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Console.WriteLine("test") End Sub` to see if it's firing but having some sort of catastrophic SQL error?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion EGC, but the issue is the firing of the event, when i click nothing happens. If I add in the tag action="home.html" on the form element, the user is redirected to the page, but nothing happens with the code behind

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40734904/11700321

Comment: @user2301960 If you use ASP.NET controls, like the [`<asp:TextBox>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.8), then you will be able to get their values with, e.g. `First_Text.Text` instead of Request.Form(...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to give each input field a [`name`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp), as that is what identifies them when posted to the server. The `id` is merely for client-side identification (e.g. via JavaScript).

```html
<input id="First_Text" name="First_Text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required />
```

Secondly, the button merely calls the callback on the server. It doesn't actually submit the form, so in this case `Request.Form` will be empty.

For standard HTML forms you need to use an `<input type="submit"/>` so that your form is actually submitted and its data sent to the server. You can then invoke the reading of its data from the `Page_Load` handler.

```html
<div class="register-buttons">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" value="Sign up"/>
</div>
```

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Check if this is a POST request.
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        DoSignUp()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DoSignUp()
    'Put your code from ValidateUser here.
End Sub
```

Although you could, [like Andrew Morton said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443379/html-button-not-firing-code-in-behind-event/58444341#comment103244327_58443379), replace the form and your input fields with ASP.NET controls and handle it via postback instead. I'm not sure which method is preferred in this case as I haven't worked much with WebForms. Personally, I'd use a form like you do now.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, that has progressed me! The only issue now is the Request.Form values are still empty any ideas?

Comment: @user2301960 : Hmm, hard to say why that is... I'll have to try this when I get back from work.

Comment: @user2301960 : Sorry for the delay, I was rather tired yesterday. Turns out the issue was quite simple and I don't know how I overlooked it. You need to have a `name="..."` attribute on your input fields as well, as that is what identifies each field when posted to the server. I have updated my answer with this info.

Comment: @user2301960 : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!